# vertex distortion in shaderlab

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, shaderlab

I'm rather new to shaderlab with unity. I am trying to distort the vertices so that they are push backwards and towards the camera almost like looking at the camera from a 45 degree angle. I am replicating an effect from a game for fun. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAKPY.png) is the code used for the effect

ive tried implenting the code into a shader script like so:

```
float4 vert(appdata v){

            float3 position = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;

            float y = position.y;
            float z = position.x;

            float3 parentTranslation = ParentMatrix._m30_m31_m32;

            position -= parentTranslation;
            position.z += AlternateLayeringScale;
            position.z -= y;
            position.y += position.z;
            position += parentTranslation + float3(0,parentTranslation.z,0);

            return position;

        }
```

however i get an error stating it cannot convert from float3 to float4, i am not sure how it was implemented

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Not really C++. Shaderlab. Unity also support GLSL.

Comment: @Programmer fixed it, thought it was c++. Still very far from c# anyway

Comment: That's right. It's far from C#

Comment: Why `position` of type `float3` must be converted at return to type `float4`? Which is the fourth component?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the code seen in the image exactly, given that a float 3 is added to it I assumed it was a float 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth part is 'w' also called the inverse stretching factor. To convert from vec4 to vec3 it's best to do `position.xyz / position.w` and to put it back in a vec4 you can write `return fixed4(position, 1)`

Comment: ive tried the code like [so](http://imgur.com/a/vLei2) but this is the outcome so [far](http://imgur.com/a/fc7ax)